# How to handle "an unhandled error caused by the Dataflow SDK" (corrupted gz as input)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to deal with "an unhandled error caused by the Dataflow SDK"?
Specifically, we have a Dataflow job that takes a list of gz files (in GCS) as input, and produces some output.
Once in a while one of the gz files may be corrupted, and the job fails because of it.
We are wondering if there is a way to handle this -- specifically, we want to make it so that the job would ignore such corrupted file(s) and proceed.
It is not clear if we can catch an exception thrown due to the corrupted gz file or not (because it appears that it is handled in Dataflow SDK itself, causing it to fail).

(For Google Dataflow team: Here is a specific dataflow job id: 2017-04-02_05_08_20-5491890758767473661.)

Update: Here's the stack trace we got from the logging UI.

```
(778029c78ed61ff2): java.io.IOException: Failed to advance reader of source: StaticValueProvider{value=gs://aaa.gz} range [0, 9223372036854775807)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.advance(WorkerCustomSources.java:544)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.advance(ReadOperation.java:425)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:217)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:220)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:170)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:192)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:172)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.read(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:278)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$TextSource$TextBasedReader.tryToEnsureNumberOfBytesInBuffer(TextIO.java:1077)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$TextSource$TextBasedReader.findSeparatorBounds(TextIO.java:1011)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$TextSource$TextBasedReader.readNextRecord(TextIO.java:1043)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.CompressedSource$CompressedReader.readNextRecord(CompressedSource.java:482)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.FileBasedSource$FileBasedReader.advanceImpl(FileBasedSource.java:536)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.OffsetBasedSource$OffsetBasedReader.advance(OffsetBasedSource.java:287)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.advance(WorkerCustomSources.java:541)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Are you getting a stack trace in Logging/the UI? I can get back to you, but it should be possible to tell the source to ignore such errors

Comment: I added the stack trace to the post. It'll be good to tell the source to ignore certain types of errors (like this one)!

Comment: I checked, and it seems that this is not currently possible. You'll need to weed out your corrupted gz files before they are read by dataflow. : (

Comment: It should also be possible to write a source that will handle a corrupted gz file more gracefully.